# Why is Wordpress commenting out my .entry-content when making it slide in and out?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to make the content of my Wordpress posts slide into view when the title of the post is clicked.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery(".entry-content").hide();
 //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
 jQuery(".entry-title").click(function()
 {
  jQuery(this).next(".entry-content").slideToggle(500);
});
});
</script>
```

Seems simple enough, but after implementing it all of a sudden my .entry-content class is being commented out.

Anyone seen this before?

Let me know if more details are necessary to explain! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the HTML with a class of entry-content being commented out, or is it commenting out part of your JQuery?

Comment: @MisterMelancholy It's giving .entry-content a class of 'display = none', which doesn't really help at all. I was thinking that clicking on the ".entry-title" would start the slideToggle and reveal the .entry-toggle but that isn't happening. Also, when I'm removing the A tag from the content.php file to stop it's refresh to that permalink, I can't click on the title to reveal the slideToggle. This is so frustrating.. learning to code this I mean...  Little help?

Comment: How is the HTML structured? Are you sure the title isn't in the content div for some bizarre reason?